# How to access cassandra database from Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, cassandra

I have intellij idea 2018.2.5 built on installed on October 16, 2018.

I'm trying to add to the panel "Database" cassandra. To do this, I go to the settings "Datasource and drivers" in Intellij and add a driver for cassandra ->
[image from intellij](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h34gC.jpg)
after that I try to create a new connection to the database, the connection is [successful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyF2r.jpg) 
but then when I want to look at the tables -> I get the error

```
Cassandra: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument for @NotNull parameter 'rs' of com/intellij/database/util/JdbcUtil.result ... more
```

and no tables are displayed.

[exception and empty table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SkGl.jpg)

maybe i need add some more settings  or driver may be incorrectly set up?

P.S.: I have created keyspace and not an empty table

Comment: Which driver are you using? Cassandra doesn't have an official JDBC driver, although I think there are a couple of proprietary ones out there

Comment: I`m using driver from Intellij Idea.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/h34gC.jpg
Maybe you know any other way? if you know please share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Intellij bundles the Cassandra JDBC driver from dbschema.com. I was able to get it to connect with a local Cassandra instance and the following configuration: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSoXy.jpg

See the docs if you have more complex configuration: https://www.dbschema.com/documentation/Cassandra/index.html

Note that as this is a JDBC driver you will need to make queries in SQL (not CQL). Also, because Cassandra is not a SQL database there are a number of features that probably won't work (inc. viewing Cassandra schema).