# Can't add Cassandra DB in IntelliJ

Tags: database, intellij-idea, cassandra

I am not able to add Cassandra DB in intelliJ project. I cant find any of Data Source window etc. Note: I have installed plugin Database Navigator and it provides me DB Browser. But when I add '+' sign only few option present, like SQL, Oracle etc, not cassandra.
My intelliJ version is 2020.3 Community edition.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access cassandra database from Intellij IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53132103/how-to-access-cassandra-database-from-intellij-idea)

Answer (score 0):

Use IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition which [has support for databases](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html), including the [Apache Cassandra](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/how-to-connect-to-cassandra-with-ssl.html):

[image]